# How to calculate 5 minute rolling mean of ATR with Pine script (TradingView)?

Tags: mean, pine-script, indicator

In TradingView Pine script, I want to calculate:

- ATR  taking high, low, close data with a timeperiod of 30 minutes
- 5 minute rolling mean of ATR

In Python, I do this:

```
# Calculate the Average True Range(ATR)
df_indicator['ATR'] = talib.ATR(df_indicator['high'], df_indicator['low'], df_indicator['close'], timeperiod=30)
# Calculate the rolling mean of ATR
df_indicator['ATR_MA_5'] = df_indicator['ATR'].rolling(5).mean()
```

How can I do this in TradingView Pine script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pine has a built-in function [atr()](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_atr).
To get the value `atr` for the current symbol on the current timeframe with a length of 30, use `atr(30)`.
To get the value `atr` for the current symbol on the timeframe 5 minute with a length of 30, use `security(syminfo.ticker, "5", atr(30))`.

Comment: And how can I calculate rolling mean of ATR?

Comment: The value `ATR` can be used as a series for any moving average, for example, `sma(atr(30), 5)`.